# New Macbook pro rarely recognizes additional display, freezes when connected

Tags: display, thunderbolt, vga

My new 13" MacBook Pro rarely recognizes a third-party display. The display works fine with a PC. It is connected via a third-party Thunderbolt/VGA adapter. Worked beautifully the first time. Now I get a "no signal" on the monitor. MacBook partially freezes. Tried rebooting, etc. No luck.

Comment: Do you happen to be running gfxCardStatus? It's an excellent utility, but there is a long standing known issue when connecting external displays while using "integrated only" mode: https://github.com/codykrieger/gfxCardStatus/issues/9

Comment: What OS? What adapter? What's in the console when the Mac freezes?